# Set several columns of a subset of an xts to NA

Tags: r, loops, subset, xts

I have an xts object `test`.

For a specific column, setting all values in year `2009` to NA

```
test$row1["2009"] <- NA
```

works like a charm, but if `test` has **several columns**, why does

```
test["2009"] <- NA
```

only set the values in 2009 from the **first column** to `NA` ? I want that it sets all values in `2009` to NA for every column.

Do I really have to use a loop/ apply here or is there an easier option?

Comment: Leave the column index empty: `test["2009", ] <- NA`

Comment: that worked!!!, could you comment below for your credits ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, leave the column index empty:

```
test["2009", ] <- NA
```

This will cause all columns to be indexed. And just row `"2009"`.